# GPU hardware specifications data?

Tags: data-request, computing

When I buy a computer, besides the price, one of the most important characteristics is the processor. [CPU DB](http://cpudb.stanford.edu) is a website that aims to list cpus hardware specifications.

Where can I get similar data for GPUs (for multiple brands)?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has comparisons of [Nvidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units), [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units), and [Intel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units) GPUs, providing tabular information on different tech specs of the graphical processing units.

Answer (score 0):

[TechPowerUp](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/index.php?mfgr%5B%5D=amd&mfgr%5B%5D=ati&mfgr%5B%5D=intel&mfgr%5B%5D=matrox&mfgr%5B%5D=nvidia&mfgr%5B%5D=xgi&class%5B%5D=desktop&class%5B%5D=mobile&class%5B%5D=workstation&igp=1&released%5B%5D=y11_c&released%5B%5D=y08_11&released%5B%5D=y05_08&released%5B%5D=y00_05&generation=&chipname=&interface=&ushaders=&tmus=&rops=&memsize=&memtype=&buswidth=&slots=&sort=released&q=or+type+to+Search...) is a not ideal, but reasonable answer.

It is not downloadable (at least not in a well structured format), but it provides a database with Chip name|Release date|Bus type|Memory|clock frequency|Memory clock|Shaders/TMUs/ROPs information about GPUS. It is possible to select data concerning the all the provided fields as well as the generation.

Comment: Nice database, but sadly not Open Data.

Comment: Alternatively, you could put the link in the question itself, as an example of what you're looking for.

Comment: I know, but this an answer, not part of the question

Comment: It is an answer, but it is definitely not the kind of answer we want to encourage here on Open Data SE. Please have a look at the related discussion at [Answers that reference paid non-open datasets](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/32/answers-that-reference-paid-non-open-datasets)

Comment: @PatrickHoefler note that the data in my answer is *free*, is just not downloadable in a good machine readable format

Comment: *Free* data it not necessarily *open* data: The most important aspect of *Open Data* is that it is published under an open license. Please refer to http://opendefinition.org/ or http://5stardata.info/ for great definitions.

Comment: that is why I wrote free in italic, there are many definitions of free. The first definition you point the classical FSF definition, the second one is better in (my opinion) because it is not too much restrictive